# Get IP or MAC addresses of Windows Multipoint Server 2012 stations?

Tags: powershell, windows-multipoint-server

Is it possible to programmatically retrieve the IP or MAC address of a station assigned to a Windows MultiPoint Server 2012 host, using PowerShell or any other .NET or Windows API?

Background: I'm developing a application to help set up USB-over-Ethernet zero clients in a WMS 2012 setup, bridging the PowerShell "WmsCmdlets" module (Microsoft.WindowsServerSolutions.MultipointServer.PowerShell.Commands.Library.WmsStation) and a third-party vendor API for configuring zero client IP address, etc. So far, I do not know any means of matching up the "stations" of the WmsCmdlets with the zero client objects in the vendor's API.

Finding out the IP or MAC associated with a WMS station would do nicely, since I have this on the zero client API side. However, I haven't found any information I could use in the PowerShell WmsCmdlets module, such as Get-WmsStation which returns the following:

```
Id                         : 1
Name                       : <my station name>
IsAutoLogOn                : False
IsSplit                    : False
CollabId                   : 0
RemoteConnectionServerName :
VirtualMachineName         :
VirtualMachineId           :
AutoLogOnUserName          :
AutoLogOnPassword          :
DeviceTypes                : {DT_Mouse, DT_Keyboard, DT_Audio, DT_MassStorage...}
DeviceCounts               : {2, 2, 0, 0...}
ComputerName               : <my WMS host server name>
SessionId                  : 4294967295
SessionHostServer          : <my WMS host server name>
```

Comment: I assumed, I could be wrong but there would only be 1 IP address per server by default (depending on your setup)

Have a look at 

ipconfig /all 

This will tell you all the IP's on the host.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a way to find the IP of the stations (the zero clients), not of the WMS host server itself. The zero clients are USB-over-Ethernet, and they do have their own IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look in the registry under
HKLM\software\microsoft\windows multipoint server\stations
You have what looks live a list of station Ids with the corresponding MAC address of the client as part of the stationhub path

Comment: Forgot to come back and update this post, but this is exactly what we ended up doing. Thanks!

Comment: Having spent a bit more time with this, there's one thing to watch out for in this approach - sometimes the registry will contain more than one entry matching the MAC address, some of them stale. To get around this, filter the results of your registry search by the Station IDs you find in a call to Get-WmsStation in PowerShell, which seems to always be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to find the IPs of other clients, but we found a major bug when you turn on the feature for each station to get a virtual IP. The second someone logs in, our DNS changes the host computer name to use that new IP, even though its IP hasn't changed. This then makes it so that RDP and remote Dashboard no longer works with the host name (the original IP of the host still works).

We had to create a special service that looks for this every few seconds and fixes our DNS server. Kind of a pain that we had to do this, but beware. Microsoft says they're going to add a patch to fix IP issues, but I'm not sure if it'll fix this particular issue.